# How to implement a simple infinite carousel in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, carousel

I am trying to implement a simple infinite carousel view for my project. I am trying to implement something like the image bellow. But I cant find where to start. I tried  with ViewPager, but i cant find a way to  show more than one carousel element in the view. Please help.

Each element in the carousel is a combination of text view and image view.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Show your code and post issues in it.

Comment: It appears you want [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) in your code, just create/remove as many as you need, and use positioning to place them side by side

Comment: @AlokNair The code I have used is https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel

Comment: I only have a text view and and image view only, is there any way to do it without fragments??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel.
One more option is of fancy coverflow
https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow.

You can achieve this infiniteness in both.

Comment: I used the same thing but I was not able to get the view I have shown above

Comment: is there any way to do it without fragments??

Comment: so many ways are there.. likewise you can do it with images, Layouts etc.

Comment: Could u please provide some code snippet, I am very new to UI design implementation.

Comment: How can i Override ListView to make it a carousel

Comment: Have you implemented FancyCoverflow?? You will be able to simply make it infinite by writing few lines of code in the getView() method of the adapter being set.

Comment: I tried using FancyCoverflow and used the same logic from previous one. It worked.....kinda... is there any correct solution insted of using 1000+ elements